# correct the mobile regex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, preg-match

I have a mobile validation regex that currently supports such input text:

```
+91xxxxxxxxxx
0091xxxxxxxxxx
```

and is valid for 10 digit mobile number starting with `9` and `8`.

Can anyone  modify the below regex so that input can start with any number from `1-9` and can also support country code format, e.g. `91xxxxxxxxxx` fail to work exaclty as I want.

Here is the regex I tried:

```
^((\+|00)\d{1,3})?[89]\d{9}$
```

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: +449807093606 ,00449807093606 is valid in my regex pattern, wanted to make  valid for +446707093606,446707093606. i have checked it in http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Please check if [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/vG1qD8/1) solves the problem.

Comment: @AshokAcharya: I added an answer, please consider accepting if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this updated regex:

```
^((\+|00)?\d{1,3})?[1-9][0-9]{9}$
```

See [demo](http:///regex101.com/r/vG1qD8/1)

**Changes made**:

- `[89]\d{9}` changed to `[1-9][0-9]{9}` to let the number start with `1` and the rest 9 digits can be any
- `(\+|00)` changed to `(\+|00)?` so that we could omit checking for these leading symbols and validate numbers starting right with the country code.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more assistance with it. If it solves your problem please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

your descriptions suggests mobile numbers start with
+918 or +919 or 00918 or 00919

`^(\+|00)91[89]\d{9}$`

Comment: eg country code accepted right now is +91,0097 and 10 digit mobile number starting with 8 or 9 will be valid, what i want with regex pattern is it  must be valid for any starting mobille number with also 91 ,+97,0091